# Copying text online, link follows when pasting

Tags: copy-paste, microsoft-onenote, links, copy, paste

Is this a Windows/Chrome feature? How can I disable this?

> Edit: It's a OneNote feature, see solution below.

When I copy text from any site, when pasting it in OneNote the link follows. For example:

```
Title 
Be specific and imagine you’re asking a question to another person 
    
From <https://superuser.com/questions/ask>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found it, it was a OneNote feature...

Disable it this way:

1. Click the three dots beneath the X in the upper right corner.
2. Settings
3. Options
4. Scroll down to the bottom, disable "Include link to source".